# How can I implement IsNull and Isempty together in sql server query

Tags: sql, sql-server

here I wanted to check if coming value is empty string or null then use value from Db column.Like I did for is null case. How can i check for empty string in this line of code.Please suggest

```
II.[NAME] = isNull(IIMODEL.[Name], II.[NAME]),
```

Comment: Can I use Case for this?

Comment: What is the "incoming" value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
II.[NAME] = ISNULL(NULLIF(TRIM(IIMODEL.[NAME]), ''), II.[NAME])
```

Comment: this works , I also tried using Case that also works,Like this II.[NAME]=CASE WHEN IIMODEL.[Name] = null THEN II.[NAME]  WHEN IIMODEL.[Name] = '' THEN II.[NAME] ELSE IIMODEL.[Name] END

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use explicit comparisons?

```
(II.[NAME] = IIMODEL.[Name] OR IIMODEL.[Name] IS NULL OR IIMODEL.[Name] = '')
```

I think the logic is much simpler to follow.

Answer (score 1):

```
case when isnull([column], '') <> '' then [column] else [other] end
```